# Apple Script no longer running with Big Sur

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-big-sur

I had this script for changing the printing paper size and saving the document pass-word protected. It was working perfectly before the software update to BigSur
The problem seems to be the line "click pop up button 3". It does not recognize the button even when it is opening the correct window which has the button I want to click. Could you please help me figuring out why it is not recognizing the pop up button?

```
set FixedPassword to "nocopy"

set VarPassword to "fibonacci"

set outpath to "/Users/E1S0.pdf"

set SaveFolder to "/Users/Exam1"

set FileName to "E1S0" & " " & "(Password" & " - " & VarPassword & ").pdf"


tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open outpath
end tell


activate application "Preview"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        keystroke "p" using command down
        delay 0.5
        tell front window
            repeat until exists sheet 1
                delay 10
            end repeat
            tell sheet 1
                click pop up button 3
                click menu item "My Customized Size" of menu 1 of pop up button 3
                click menu button "PDF"
                repeat until exists menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
                    delay 0.02
                end repeat
                click menu item "Save as PDF" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
                
            end tell
        end tell
        
        -- Make sure the save dialog is visible
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        tell sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            click button "Security Options..."
        end tell
        
        tell window "PDF Security Options"
            set selected to true
            set focused to true
            (* click the checkbox to on *)
            -- NOTE: for some reason there is a delay of about 6 seconds here, I do not know why
            tell checkbox "Require password to open document"
                click
            end tell
            (* add the password and confirm *)
            keystroke VarPassword
            keystroke (ASCII character 9)
            keystroke VarPassword
            
            tell its checkbox "Require password to copy text, images and other content"
                click
            end tell
            (* add the password and confirm *)
            keystroke FixedPassword
            keystroke (ASCII character 9)
            keystroke FixedPassword
            
            click button "OK"
        end tell
        
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        -- Press command+shift+g to show the "Go" drop down sheet
        keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
        repeat until exists sheet of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        delay 0.5
        keystroke SaveFolder
        delay 0.5
        
        click button "Go" of sheet of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        
        -- Now that we are in our desired folder, set the file name and save
        set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window to FileName
        
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Please add a screen shot of the **UI** you are trying to control.  What is the _name_ of the _button_ you want to _click_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not usual for **AppleScript** *code* to be broken between major releases of **macOS**.

If the *button* you are trying to *click* happens to be **Paper Size:**, which by default does not show on the target *sheet*, then its *hierarchy* has changed between e.g. **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur**.

In **macOS Catalina** its *hierarchy* is:

**AXApplication** > **AXWindow:AXStandardWindow** > **AXSheet** > **AXPopUpButton**

Or:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click pop up button 3 of ¬
        sheet 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
```

In **macOS Big Sur** its *hierarchy* is:

**AXApplication** > **AXWindow:AXStandardWindow** > **AXSheet** > **AXSplitGroup** > **AXPopUpButton**

Or:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click pop up button 3 of ¬
        splitter group 1 of ¬
        sheet 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
```

---

That said, as previously mentioned by default that button does not show on the target *sheet* and you should include *code* that checks that the *sheet* has been expanded to show details and if not click the **Show Details** *button* first.

Comment: Thanks that worked but now I get another error: "Can’t get menu item "My Customized Size" of menu 1 of pop up button 3 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process "Preview"."